# Finite groups and prime divisors. Understanding how to deduce a claim from a certain proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, group-actions

In my algebra textbook, it goes like this. First, there is presented Cauchy's theorem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $|G|$. Then $G$ contains an element of order $p$.

Then goes the proof:

> Consider the set
>
> $S = \{(a_1, ..., a_p)| a_1...a_p = e_G \} \subseteq G^p$
>
> Once $a_1, ... a_p$ are chosen (arbitrarily), then $a_p$ is determined  is determinaed uniquely as the inverse of $a_1...a_{p-1}$. Then $|S| = |G|^{p-1}$, so $p$ divides the order of $S$ as it divides the order of $G$.
>
> Now we may act with the group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ on $S$: given $[m]_p \in  \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, $0 \leq m < p$, act by $[m]_p$ on
>
> $(a_1, ..., a_p)$
>
> by sending it to
>
> $(a_{m+1}, ..., a_p, a_1, ..., a_m)$, which is still an elements of $S$.
>
> Now we know that $|Z| \equiv |S| \equiv 0 \mod p$,
>
> where $Z$ is the set of pixed points of this action. That is, $Z = \{ (a, ..., a)| a^p = e_G \} \subseteq G^p$. Note that $Z \neq \varnothing$,since $(e_G, ..., e_G) \in Z$. Since $p \geq 2$ and $p$ divides $|Z|$, we conclude that $|Z| > 1$; therefore there exists some element in $Z$ of the form $(a, ..., a)$ with $a \neq e_G$. Then $\exists \ \ a \in G \setminus \{e_G \}: \ \ a_p = e_G$, then the order of $a$ is $p$.

Now the reader is asked to prove the following claim:

> Let $G$ be a finite group, let $p$ be a prime divisor of $|G|$, and let $N$ be the number of cyclic subgroups of $G$ of order $p$. Then $N \equiv 1 \mod p$.

I have a problem now. Isn't $N = |Z| - 1$? Because we don't count $e_G$.
If $|Z| = pk, k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $N = |Z| - 1 = pk - 1$, so $N \equiv -1 \mod p$.

Could you, please, point at my mistake? Can't see it at the moment, even though I suspect it might be obvious.

Comment: The question is about the number of subgroups of order $p$, which is $|Z|/(p-1)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt But any subgroup of order $p$ is cyclic by Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation $\lvert N \rvert=\lvert Z\rvert-1$ is wrong. Not every element of $Z$ maps to a distinct cyclic subgroup.

For every cyclic subgroup of order $p$, we have $e_G$ and then we have $p-1$ other elements of order $p$. Thus, for each cyclic subgroup, we add $p-1$ elements to $Z$. Therefore, $Z$ has $1$ element for $e_G$ and $p-1$ elements for each cyclic subgroup. If we say the number of cyclic subgroups are $N$, then we get:
$$\lvert Z \rvert=1+(p-1)\lvert N \rvert$$
As you said, we should substitute $pk$ for $\lvert Z\rvert$:
$$pk=1+(p-1)\lvert N \rvert$$
Solve for $\lvert N \rvert$:
$$\lvert N\rvert=\frac{pk-1}{p-1}$$
Both the numerator and the denominator are $\equiv -1 \pmod p$, so we find that $\lvert N\rvert \equiv (-1)(-1)^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: Of course! For example, $a^{p-1} \neq a$ if the order of $a$ is $p$. But $\langle a \rangle = \langle a^{p-1} \rangle$, right? So the mapping $\{a \in G \mid a \neq e_G, a^p = e_G \} \to \{$ cyclic subgroups of order $p \ \ \}$ is surjective, but not injective.

Comment: Yes, the mapping of elements of order $p$ to cyclic subgroups of order $p$ is surjective, but not injective. (Also, personally, I like to use \mid for set-builder notation.)

Comment: Can you, please, explain why $a \equiv c \mod p, b \equiv c \mod p, a = tb \Rightarrow t \equiv 1 \mod p$?

Comment: If we have $a=tb$, then we have $c \equiv tc \pmod p$. When we multiply both sides of the equation by the modular inverse of $c \pmod p$ (which exists because $p$ is prime and I assume $c \neq 0$), we find that $1 \equiv t \pmod p$.